# Is This Book Wrong? (Points at Infinity on $2Y^2 = X^4 - 17$)

Tags: solution-verification, elliptic-curves, projective-space

I am working through an exercise (below) in the book 'Diophantine Geometry: An Introduction' which asserts that the curve $2 Y^2 = X^4 - 17$ has two points at infinity, neither of which are $\mathbb{Q}$-rational.

[image: Question from book]

This is incorrect, right... or am I missing something here?!

Homogenizing, we get $2Y^2 Z^2 = X^4 - 17Z^4$, so setting $Z=0$ gives $X = 0$, and hence, the *unique* point at infinity should be $[0; 1; 0]$ (which *is* rational over $\mathbb{Q}$)...

I would appreciate if someone could just verify this for me.

Comment: Maybe homogenizing doesn't yet give "the *smooth* projective curve" and you need to do some blowups at $[0;1;0]$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your're right - it's not smooth... I am still learning about elliptic curves, so it looks like I will need to read up on blowups...